# Can you "set a persistent size for saving changes" after creating the Bootable USB?

Tags: boot, usb

I have created a bootable Ubuntu USB and I realized when I was restarting my PC none of my changes were being saved. After some searching i realized this was because I didn't allow extra space for things to save e.g. my wallpaper and search history, i was just wondering if there is any way to do this from inside Ubuntu or if I have to reinstall from universal usb installer - linux pen drive?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PenDriveLinux for quite some time and remembered that there is in fact a way you can do this, but it will require you to reinstall the version you want.

Here is a post on there website: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/

Hope this helps.